# TCP Sockets in Android

Tags: android, sockets, android-networking

I have 2 mobile devices connected to a wireless network to provide internet.

I want to connect the 2 devices using Sockets(TCP).

Here is my code on server mobile.

```
     ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
     Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
```

Here is the code on client

```
     Socket s = new Socket("local ip address of server mobile",SERVERPORT);
```

I have added required permission in both the phones. But the application in both the phones is stuck at this point(I have tested that).
Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Also, are these sockets TCP sockets by default?

Comment: java.net.Socket is TCP Based. How do you know the server IP address? Can client can ping the server?

Comment: Please clarify: "wireless network" as in WLAN or as in "mobile cellular" GSM/WCDMA?